# node scripts/install.js doesnt point to the correct right url

Tags: javascript, node.js

This 404 error happens for many packages but not all. I am quite new to node js and I cannot figure out how to fix this. I am working on ubuntu 16.04

I can not think of what other details should be provided so please suggest that too.

```
mendu@peanutbutter:~/node$ sudo npm install   tcp-port-used tar-fs request-progress ht-auth express-ws node-pty -g --unsafe-perm

> node-pty@0.6.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-pty
> node scripts/install.js

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 response downloading https://nodejs.org/download//v8.1.1/node-v8.1.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:210:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1074:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:564:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:453:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-62-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-pty
gyp ERR! node -v v8.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN express-ws@3.0.0 requires a peer of express@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0-alpha.1 but none was installed.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty@0.6.8 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty@0.6.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mendu/.npm/_logs/2017-06-14T13_22_04_259Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Easiest Solution

For the time being, roll your node version back to at least `8.1.0`.  This is an issue with node `8.1.1`.

The most conservative way to run node, which will result in the fewest issues like this, is to always run an LTS version (details: https://github.com/nodejs/LTS).  So I would recommend using node `6.11`.

#### More Details & Workaround

The issue is being tracked at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13667

As noted in that ticket workaround is running ([see @addaleax's tweet](https://twitter.com/addaleax/status/874902309008011264)):

```
npm config set dist-url https://nodejs.org/download/release/
```

Answer (score -2):

did you try installing node-gyp with -g first ?
and than maybe express and the other packages step by step...